# List index value retrieval

Tags: java

I have list having data like a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
 if i want this list i would say getList(); which returns me a arraylist,i need only the value at index 10 that is 'i' ,how would i do this ?

Comment: Java uses 0-based indexes. The tenth element in a list is at index 9, not 10. Furthermore, you only have 9 elements in your example list, so 'i' would be at index 8.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
getList().get(8);
```

Have in mind that index is 0-based. So index `8` means the `9th` item.

Advice: always look at the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/), or open the autocomplete of your IDE, to see what methods does your object have. Most of them are named and documented in a way that it is explicitly known what they actually do.

For example, in your case, google for "ArrayList", open the first result (from java.sun.com), and look through the methods there.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, it actually has a separate Javadoc pane you can add to UI, you can find it from `Window -> Show View -> Java/Javadoc` It even reacts automatically to where your cursor is in source file which is incredibly handy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with [get()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29).

BTW, you can find the complete Java API docs [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/). I'd highly recommend bookmarking it.

Comment: Your link is pointing to the javadoc for the unreleased Java 7

Comment: Of course, one should bookmark the right version of the Java API docs (you link to Java 7 beta, which OP probably does not use)